# Where can I get ore to paint the Regalia?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I want to paint my car all of the colors, because I'm indecisive and don't know what I like best. Unfortunately, I need quite a bit of ore to repair my car. Occasionally I'll come across some blackstone or even the illusion bluestone ore, but I can't find them reliably. I know they're typically found in rocky outcrops, but is there any strategy for finding a lot of them?

Comment: First port of call would be to visit local restaurants and speak to the proprietor, this will mark procurement points on your map, but you'd still need to visit them each time and collect the ores.

Comment: @DavidYell That's the answer, I'd suggest you write it in the answer box =)

Comment: @CyberClaw True, but it doesn't answer the bulk aspect of the question, and I'm not sure farming ores is a good answer - even if it could be the only way.

Comment: @DavidYell if it's the only way, then that's the answer, I'd say. I was hoping there was a way to get a lot quickly, though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found any means to obtain bulk lots of ore, so far in my gameplay (Chapter 6 30h+).

The best way to gather ores is to speak to a local restaurant proprietor, who will mark the local procurement points on your map. The pickaxe icons are the ones to keep an eye out for.

Then you'll need to visit these spots and collect the ore. The procurement spots do seem to regenerate after a time. So you can 'farm' these ore nodes by revisiting them once they've regenerated. The icon will change from grey back to yellow.

Unfortunately I haven't been paying enough attention to notice if certain ores spawn in the same spot each time, so that you can gather multiples of the same. I know the treasure spots do contain the same items every time though, so the ores may well do as well.